# Angular Websocket connection timeout with Django Channels

Tags: django, angular, amazon-ec2, websocket, django-channels

I'm currently having an issue with my websocket timing out with the following error message

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

My websocket connection via Django Channels works on my local, but on the server it just times out (not even hitting the onOpen console log). I'm not sure at all what the issue is and I'm very new to websockets so I was hoping someone could help. Below is how I'm instantiating my websocket. This is done on the aws ec2 if that is relevant.

```
    this.ws = new WebSocket('wss://api.example.com:9000/aurl/');
```

With my channel layers as such

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

I'm pretty sure the routing is correct as it works in my local, so I have no idea where the error originates from. I tried using both daphne and redis

using `'BACKEND': 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer'`
but that didn't seem to work either, daphne is set up to run on port 9000. I feel like this is a simple error relating to the actual port numbers but I don't know.

**Edit**: On my local I'm using `this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/aurl/');` for the creation of the websocket

Comment: `this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/aurl/');` or `this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/url/');`

Comment: That wouldn't work because without wss it goes through http, but the application redirects http requests and gives s 301 error, so it has to be wss for https request

Comment: try `this.ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.com:8000/aurl/');`

Comment: I just get an error code 503 for that